# How to read arguments from target

Tags: c++

When you right click on a program in windows(such as starcraft.exe) and look at its properties there is a text field called "target" which contains the full path of the binary. I have seen programs able to parse flags added to the target such as "C:\programfiles\myprogram\myprogram.exe -x 1280 -y 360" and the program would start up in the specified resolution. My question is how to read those arguments, if it is done by argv[] please just inform me of my stupidity.

C++ is the language, VS express 2012 desktop is the environment.

Comment: Yes, those are normal command line arguments. If, on the other hand, you're after retrieving the command line string from the shortcut, there's a shell interface that you can use for that.

Answer (score 1):

you receive those parameters when calling executable main method `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` as argc (count) and argv[] parameters all you have to do is just parse them

here is an example [How to parse command line parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/13355/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to avoid comparisons between char* and string literals without strncmp.
Remember that argc is the the argument count (including the program name).

argv is an array of C strings specifying the arguments (first being the program name as invoked).

In this case, you're usually best off using a library, like [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).  This will make interleaved options, long options, and arguments much more sane to manage (assuming order between options and arguments is largely unimportant).